# How Twilio accounts are related to regular user accounts in a customized solution?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am completely new in Twilio and I am considering to build an app where users can make calls to phone numbers.

From Twilio side of things, I guess we need to have Twilio accounts for each user (where each user will have it's own Twilio phone number, required for the ability to make calls).

So I guess that we need to have regular user accounts in our DB and for each regular user, to store Twilio auth token (and other Twilio credentials if needed) as a user fields. When user needs to make a call, we just use the corresponding auth token.

The users themselves, have Twilio accounts and numbers, but they should not be aware of them. They are only aware of the app, where they login and make calls. I guess that admin should create their Twilio accounts in the Twilio console for them? I am OK with admin paying the bills for the calls, since users will be doing the calls on admin's request.

Is that how Twilio should work and how it should be connected to the regular user profiles, for the cases when we have fully customized UI?

Answer (score 0):

you create your master twilio account. Then everytime a user creates an account on your app, you programmatically create a sub account for each of your users. Then when you buy phone numbers, you buy them through your master account credentials, and pass the phone number down to the sub account. pretty sure thats how it works. check this passport login i created for something like that

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: keys.googleClientID,
        clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({googleId: profile.id})
        if (existingUser) {
            done(null, existingUser)
                } else {
                    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); // get our master account credentials
                    const actServiceSid = await client.api.accounts // create sub account, this variable holds the return data
                    .create({friendlyName: profile.displayName }) // name it with profiles displayName ex. Christian Moosey
                    .then(account => { return {sid: account.sid, authToken: account.authToken}}) // return our new sub account auth credentials
                   const subClient = require('twilio')(actServiceSid.sid, actServiceSid.authToken) // these are our sub account credentials
                    const msgServiceSid = await subClient.messaging.services // subaccount credentails / whatever service we need
                        .create({
                            friendlyName: profile.displayName,
                            inboundRequestUrl: "http://a30-b81e-5e93-f40b-34f.ngrok.io/webhook-incoming-message"
                        }) // create messaging service name
                        .then(service => { return console.log(service), {sid: service.sid}}) // return the sid in an object
                    const convoServiceSid = await subClient.conversations.services // subaccount credentials / create conversations service
                    .create({friendlyName: profile.displayName}) // make it look like christian moreno
                    .then(service => { return {sid: service.sid}}); // return and object with a sid key to convoServiceSid variable
                    const keys = await subClient.newKeys.create({friendlyName: profile.displayName})
                    .then(new_key => { return { keySid: new_key.sid, keySec: new_key.secret}})
                    const twimlApp = await subClient.applications
                    .create({
                    voiceMethod: 'POST',
                    voiceUrl: 'https://-00-96fb.ngrok.io/voice',
                    friendlyName: 'Phone Me'
                    })
                    .then(application => { return {twimlApp: application.sid}});
                    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                      }).then(customer => { return {customerId: customer.id}});
                    const user = await new User({ 
                        googleId: profile.id,
                        displayName: profile.displayName,
                        image: profile.photos[0].value,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
                        lastName: profile.name.familyName,
                        msgServiceSid: msgServiceSid.sid,
                        convoServiceSid: convoServiceSid.sid,
                        subActServiceSid: actServiceSid.sid,
                        subActAuthToken: actServiceSid.authToken,
                        stripeCustomerId: customer.customerId,
                        twilKeySid: keys.keySid,
                        twilKeySec: keys.keySec,
                        twimlAppSid: twimlApp.twimlApp
                        }).save()
                    done(null, user);

                    
                }
        }
    )
)
```